# How to compile a CUDA program with an specific toolkit version?

Tags: cuda

I have cuda toolkit 5.5 and 5.0 installed in my ubuntu system,I want to compile the .cu file with specific version..how to do that ?

Comment: are you building code in Windows or Linux or OS X? There isn't a universal solution that applies to all of them afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by setting proper environment variables. The following example is for CUDA 5.5 on x86_64 machine.

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-5.5
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```